# jQuery change var by event in real time - not work

Tags: jquery

How make change "aspectRatio" in settings https://github.com/trentrichardson/UberUploadCropper/blob/master/example-advanced/index.php in real time.

```
$(function() {

$.("#test1").click( function () {
    $ratio = 1;
});
$.("#test2").click( function () {
    $ratio = 2;
});

$('#UploadImages').uberuploadcropper({

...

'aspectRatio': $ratio,
```

It not work. Why?
How it is correct to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a global variable of the `$ratio`.

Example:

```
var $ratio; //Define a global variable like this
$(function() {

    $("#test1").click( function () {
        $ratio = 1;
        initPlugin();
    });
    $("#test2").click( function () {
        $ratio = 2;
        initPlugin();
    });

    function initPlugin() {    
        $('#UploadImages').uberuploadcropper({

             ...

             'aspectRatio': $ratio, //now the value will be taken from global scope
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It did not help. "uberuploadcropper" loaded with a empty value, and will block all further changes ratio.

Comment: And upload button not visible.

Comment: @МихаилДмитриев, There were some syntactical and few logical errors too. Please see the update.

Comment: Thanks. Upload button visible. But $ratio empty, vars not updates after click.

Answer (score 0):

remove dot **.** after `$.("`

```
$("#test1").click( function () {
    $ratio = 1;
});
$("#test2").click( function () {
    $ratio = 2;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the plugin before the variable is set. You must call .uberuploadcropper when the click event fires. Try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.("#test1").click( function () {
        uploadCropper(1);
    });
    $.("#test2").click( function () {
        uploadCropper(2);
    });

    function uploadCropper(ratio){
        $('#UploadImages').uberuploadcropper({

            ...

            'aspectRatio': ratio, //now the value will be taken from global scope
        });
    }
});
```